# ¿Como uso datos serializados en Python?

Tags: html, python

Tengo la siguiente web:

```
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#boton1').click(function(){

        var dataString = $('#form1').serialize();

        alert('Datos serializados: '+dataString);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/cgi-bin/script.py",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<body>
<form id="form1" data-ajax="false">
<label for="slider-fill">Input slider:</label>
<input type="range" name="slider-fill" id="slider-fill" value="90" min="0" max="180" data-highlight="true">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="boton1">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Como podéis ver lo que hace es enviarle información a `/cgi-bin/script.py` y esa información esta serializada. El problema es que no se como recogerla en el script para mas tarde enviársela a un Arduino. Esto es lo que tengo escrito en Python:

```
import cgi, cgitb
import serial
cgitb.enable()

ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
searchterm =  form.getvalue('form1')
ser.write(str(searchterm) + "1")
```

No me funciona y no se muy bien que hacer.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64743/discussion-on-question-by-orizzon-como-uso-datos-serializados-en-python).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es probable que no te funcione porque estás confundiendo los parámetros enviados en el formulario.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import cgi, cgitb, json, time
import serial
cgitb.enable()

print 'Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8\n\n'
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
# Esperamos que el arduino se resetee tras abrir el puerto
time.sleep(5)
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
searchterm =  form.getvalue('slider-fill')
ser.write(str(searchterm) + "1")
print json.dumps({'resultado': True, 'enviado': searchterm})
```

Por último debes darle permisos de ejecución al script con un `chmod a+x script.py`.

En tu HTML tienes campos `<input>` que son referenciados por su atributo `name`, no el identificador del formulario, `form1`.

Tal y como te dije en los comentarios, es importante que el usuario `www-data` esté en el grupo `dialup`. Para agregarlo haz:

```
$ sudo adduser www-data dialup
$ sudo service lighttpd restart
```

En HTML debes modificar el javascript para evitar el envío del formulario usando [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#boton1').click(function(evento){
        /* Cancelamos el envío del formulario */
        evento.stopPropagation();
        evento.preventDefault();

        var dataString = $('#form1').serialize();

        alert('Datos serializados: '+dataString);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/cgi-bin/script.py",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<body>
<form id="form1" data-ajax="false">
<label for="slider-fill">Input slider:</label>
<input type="range" name="slider-fill" id="slider-fill" value="90" min="0" max="180" data-highlight="true">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="boton1">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Si lo deseas no es necesario que serialices todo el formulario, también podrías montar tu propia petición con los datos que mejor te convengan de la siguiente manera:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/cgi-bin/script.py",
        data: {
            'slider-fill': $('#slider-fill').val(),
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
```

Si no queremos esperar a que el arduino se resetee cada vez que abrimos el puerto podemos crear este script perl para que deshabilite el uso de [DTR (la señal que indica al arduino que acabamos de abrir el puerto)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Terminal_Ready):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Device::SerialPort;
my $port = Device::SerialPort->new("/dev/ttyACM0");
$port->databits(8);
$port->baudrate(9600);
$port->parity("none");
$port->stopbits(1);
$port->dtr_active(0);
```

Para instalar `Device::SerialPort` debes ejecutar:

```
$ sudo cpan Device::SerialPort
```

El script habría que ejecutarlo una única vez cada vez que se conecte el arduino al puerto USB.

PD: Como comentamos en el chat, esto último no funciona en Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionarme. La verdad no se si es que no he puesto bien el CGI en mi servidor o algo. También me han comentado que para hacerlo debería usar Flask.

Comment: Es otra opción. ¿Has activado la depuración? ¿Y en la consola de depuración del navegador qué te sale?

Comment: Voy a solicitar mover los comentarios al chat para poder comunicarnos de manera más ágil.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Una cosa que quiero comentar es que cuando muevo el servo primero se posicione en 90 grados y luego va a la posición que yo le he mandado. Creo que es por el `time.sleep` que al final le he puesto un valor de 1.

Comment: Eso es porque tu programa arduino, en el setup probablemente, prefija una posición tras el reset.